# JQUERY : Website without reload, back and forward do not work after refresh

Tags: jquery, dynamic, back, forward

I'm trying to do my portfolio without reload page. I've got an issue that I can't resolved.

When I click on a link, the next link is loaded but when I go back to the first link and refresh the page. The back and the forward are not dynamic anymore.

How can I please resolved this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Here my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a').live('click', function(event){
    //LOAD PAGE ON CLICK
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#md').fadeOut(200, function(e) {
        $(this).load(link + ' .md', function(e) {
            $(this).fadeIn(200);
        });
    });
    //LOAD PAGE CHANGE HISTORY
    window.history.pushState(null, null, link);
    popstate = function(url){$('#md').load(url + ' #md');}
    window.onpopstate = function(event){popstate(window.location.href);event.preventDefault();}
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: `live` is deprecated. You should look at `delegate` or `on`

Comment: I don't think it come from there. I already try with `on` or `bind` it doesn't change anything. I'm pretty sure it comes from the
`//LOAD PAGE CHANGE HISTORY` part

Comment: Here the new code no more `.live`

`//DYNAMIC LOAD
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on('click', 'a', function(event)`

But I still can't go back and foward after the reload, anyone please.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected my code for the recent jquery

But I still don't know why the onpopstate do not save the history after the reload then the back and forward do not work anymore...

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){
    //LOAD PAGE ON CLICK
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#md').fadeOut(200, function() {
        $(this).load(link + ' .md', function() {
            $(this).fadeIn(200);
        });
    });
    //SAVE HISTORY
    window.history.pushState({}, null, link + ' ');
    //BACK/FORWARD HISTORY
    popstate = function(url){
        $('#md').fadeOut(200, function() {
            $(this).load(url + ' #md', function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(200);
            });
        });
    }
    //SAVE LINK BACK/FORWARD HISTORY
    window.onpopstate = function(event){
        popstate(window.location.href);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    //RETURN FALSE
    return false;
});
```